# Cordova WebVR App Flicker on Android

Tags: cordova, three.js, webvr

I'm using WebVR Boilerplate with Cordova for a VR app using 360 video.

I'm testing on a Huawei 9 (Android 7) and have a problem with a flickering screen as you rotate the device and watch video. This doesn't happen on any of the other Android device, or when I load it in the browser on this device.

I've looked for other help on this and other problems note that the camera needs a near of 100 which I've done in Three.js.

I'm using the WebVR boilerplate, and interestingly when I press the fullscreen button the problem goes away, however if you then touch the screen the view goes black.

Love some help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a container for the renderer rather than attaching it straight to body.